# Can`t divide two INTEGERS in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Why do I get 3 when I execute this T-SQL script:

```
SELECT 10/3;
```

I have tried :

```
SELECT CAST((10/3) AS decimal(5,2));
```

But now I get 3.00 - still not what I expected

Comment: `SELECT 10/3.0;`  note the 3.0  (now the 3 is a decimal and it will work)

Answer (score 4):

If you are using two integers in a division it will do integer division.  You need to cast at least one of the integers to float or decimal *before* the division to get what you are looking for.

Answer (score 4):

`{int}/{int}={int}`. SQL Server, or any *good* language fior that matter, won't implicitly change the data type of a expressions results when only 1 data type is involved (in this case `int`). Thus `10/3 = 3` is correct.

As for the latter, you *still* have `{int}/{int}={int}`, but you then convert the **result** to a `decimal`. `3` as a `decimal` is `3.00` so that too is correct.

You need to convert one of values *before* you divide; changing the data type of either the dividend or the divisor works. For example:

```sql
SELECT (10 * 1.) / 3,
       10 / CONVERT(decimal(2,0),3);
```

Comment: Definitely the more complete answer